# Need suggestion for custom page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am applying a custom theme in word press. I have worked on custom type posts and their custom templates like archive-{custom-post-type}.php

Now i have to work on page by default wordpress just give title and description area for pages. Can I make different pages as custom post type with custom fields, sub titles and more images featured?

I need suggestion on this mock up, should i make different posts with category about-us and tags like #managent-gallery, #life-at-company etc and fetch these posts and show them at page-{about-us}.php or should I do something else.

[image]

Comment: Please see this link, it will help you. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159942/adding-content-areas-to-custom-page-template#answer-249632

Comment: Thanks @HassanShafique

Comment: What you actually want ? Please elaborate you questions more.

Comment: Instead using plugin you can create your custom fields by creating custom meta box.

Comment: @dineshkashera why i shouldn't  use Advance custom plugin ? is there any reason?

Comment: you have to use only 3 fields, it will increase unnecessary loading times in admin side. If you need more customization then it will be better to go with plugins, But i think for 3 fields  its not good ideas. :)

Comment: no i need many fields in different custom post types and different pages.